# MVC4 OAuthWebSecurity with Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

I have successfully implemented an MVC4 website with simplemembership and OAuthWebSecurity.
i already have the same app working in android using the httprest and passing the userid.

What is the best way to use this same security model from a mobile device, specifically Android? Can I? or do i have to use the other oauth solutions out there?

I can hack my way around the simple membership, but i cant seem to do it with the OAuthWebSecurity (probably for good reasons)

Android and the website will do the exact same thing. i do not want to use the html5 mobile stuff with mvc.